# How to append string literals to properties returned from a Select-Object command

Tags: powershell

How do you concatenate a string literal and parameter in a `Select-Object`.

For Example I have:

```
Get-AdUser -filter * | Select-Object 'sip'+SamAccountName,Name, Email, etc
```

Basically I want to return the property `SamAccountName` from the AdUser with the string literal `sip` before it.

I tried everything I can think of.

Thanks!

Edit: added parameters and multiple users

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can specify an expression in a script block to do this. Like this:

```
 Get-AdUser foo@bar.com | select-object {"sip"+$_.SamAccountName}
```

Though if you do it this way, the name of resultant property looks a bit weird. To specify the property name as well, enclose the script block as part of a hashtable that specifies the name of the new property as well as the scriptblock expression to generate it. It would look like this:

```
Get-AdUser foo@bar.com | select-object @{name="SamAccountName"; expression={"sip"+$_.SamAccountName}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `Select-Object`, because you're not trying to create a new object with specific properties; you're trying to select a single property (`SamAccountName`) and manipulate it.

```
"sip" + (Get-ADUser foo@bar.com).SamAccountName
```

Comment: Yeah I probably didn't have a good example there. I'm trying to return all users (-filter *) and multiple properties (Name, Email, etc).